# See all the related files while loading a Page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a huge web project and need to fix some small issues.
Unfortunately I need to find the right files to edit, in order that the changes can take place.

For example:
I have a menu bar on the Admin Page, which is splitted in 10-15 other PHP Files.
I want to increase the clickable area of the buttons of this menubar.
How can I use the google devtools or other recommended tools, in order to find the right path and line code to the file.

I have the same question with all the other functionalities.
Lets say I have a problem with an email sending form.
Is there a tool, which can spit out the error message.
I need some clues in order to get started.

Comment: No, if there would be a tool to spot every bug automatically, a lot of developers would loose their job :)

Comment: haha sounds legit :D. But there must be some kind of help.